# Free eBook reader having capability to convert mobi to PDF format

Tags: gratis, pdf, windows-7, ebooks

I'm looking a free eBook reader for Windows 7 having capability to convert mobi to PDF format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) does that - and lots more;

For any book in your Calibre library just right click->Convert Books->Convert Individually (or bulk but here's instructions for individually).

A dialogue will pop up:
[image]

Just select PDF for output format over at the top-right.

There are lots of options but you can just use default and usually get a reasonably output.
Click OK and it'll convert in the background.

Comment: That would be exactly my recommendation as well (see also [my answer here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1427/185)). The latest versions do not only offer a reader and converter, but also include editing functionality. Having a nice, browse-able catalog of your eBooks is a nice side-effect :)