# Ebook Managment, Rating, Sharing platform

Tags: ebooks, sharing

I'm looking for software/website like imdb, trakt.tv or steam for ebook managment.

Thinks i'd like to see:

- rating of Ebooks (like imdb) and Sharing of ratings with friends
- track authors or series
- Calender which shows:

  - when an author (to which i am subscribed) launches a new book
  - a series has a new book
- User reviews
- ... More in that general direction

It would be nice if it is an local program that can also manage ebooks and is able to do conversions, but i have the feeling, that an online solution might be better. (Like trakt.tv + XBMC addon)

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), which I recommended already in [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1427/185). I'm not sure if it's a perfect match for you, as I never tried to share ratings (or have multiple ratings for a given book), and don't know about the calendar facilities. But it works locally, and has a built-in webserver so your friends can access your collection if you want them too.