# Web page to PDF converter

Tags: pdf, html, css, document-converter, file-converter

I am looking for a JavaScript or PHP plugin/library to convert a beautifully designed website (using CSS) to PDF file.

To clarify further, I need to convert the HTML-CSS output on the webpage to PDF file. I found some interesting plugins related to JavaScript like jsPDF but it only converts HTML to PDF, ignoring CSS. Which is not what I want.

Some points:

- The generated PDF file should have output of both HTML and CSS.
- Should work on both Mac and Windows.
- Should work on latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

PS: The elements are being added dynamically using JavaScript. Suppose a scenario where there are lot of different styled sections. User can add or remove those styled sections, and later he/she can press on a button "create as PDF".

Comment: Not what you want, but the least effort solution if to use the browser's print menu to "print to PDF"

Comment: @Mawg I can't say users to do that steps manually. So, looking for solution through JS or Php.

Comment: Then why not Google for `js  pdf screenshot`?  For instance, this looks helpful ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee  of course, I have only grazed here, and not verified that it is is PDF and not PNG or JPEG, which is why this is a comment, and not an answer. But surely you are not inventing an entirely new wheel?

Comment: There is an excllent article explaining how to do so at http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: I would think that you cannot do this server side unless you generate the entire page, js, css & all server-side (and, even then, it would be hideously complex). Since the page gets rendered client side, look for a client side solution.

Comment: See also https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-export-my-HTML-page-as-PDF-using-JavaScript

Comment: Don't be afraid to consider two step solutoins. There are plenty of examples of how to save a web page to JPG or PNG. The second step is then to generate a PDF document containing that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [WeasyPrint](https://weasyprint.org/)

Free (under a BSD license) and [open-source](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint) solution helping web developers to create PDF documents. It turns simple HTML pages (with CSS, SVG and so on) into PDF format. It aims to support web standards for printing.

#### `html-pdf` (npm)

You can use NodeJS [`html-pdf` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) (see [GitHub](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf), install via: `npm install -g html-pdf`). Sample shell command-line:

```
html-pdf http://example.com/ example.pdf
```

---

#### PhantomJS

Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) with [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js), Sample command-line:

```
phantomjs rasterize.js http://example.com/
```

---

#### `wkhtmltopdf`

Use [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (see: [GitHub page](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf)) command-line tool to convert the website into the PDF page.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) asks `Is it possible to capture or print what's displayed in an html canvas as an image or pdf?` and the answer by @lepe, who seems to know what he is talking abbout, with 13.6k rep, which has 16 upvotes, says

> I would use "[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)". It just work great. It uses webkit
>   engine (used in Chrome, Safari, etc.), and it is very easy to use:
>
> wkhtmltopdf stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/ this_question.pdf
>
> That's it!
>
> [Try it](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

The recommendation is endorsed by [Mr JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183624/mr-javascript), who sounds like he knows what he is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html), which is an excellent headless browser, great for development porpoises, says

> Since PhantomJS is using WebKit, a real layout and rendering engine,
>   it can capture a web page as a screenshot.

and

> Beside PNG format, PhantomJS supports JPEG, GIF, and PDF.

It is really simple to use. Here's some sampel code for captureing as .PNG

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I tried converting http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35963/web-page-to-pdf-converter  but it guts left edge and the questions on the right are not present.  It does have clickable links so yay!

Comment: If it doesn't work, why say "yay"? I am confused

Comment: because at least the links are clickable.  Many other products are not.

Comment: At this point, I can't recommend anything else, but if you post your code to http://stackoverflow.com/ you should get some help there