# PDF library management and viewer

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, pdf-viewer

I look for a PDF viewer which also offers some sort of document management. I have a lot of PDF files which I wish to tag, classify, …

Then I look for a PDF viewer with at least the following features:

- free
- view PDF files (editing or highlighting tools is a plus)
- open PDF files (as the default application)
- allow to tag the file
- manage files according to the tags or other properties
- Works on Windows

I found [Benubird PDF](http://www.debenu.com/products/desktop/debenu-pdf-benubird/) which is nice, but it doesn't open PDF files when it's selected as the default program.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Retagging/Renaming software for ebooks](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1418/185). Though the question title implies a different "target", the recommended software (Calibre) does all that and more: tagging, descriptions, search, full ebook management, conversions, etc. It comes with a document viewer as well; as I rarely work with PDF, I cannot refer to that – but the viewer works fine with e.g. epub and mobi. As *Calibre* also supports PDF, I'd guess it works with that as well – but I didn't try. Worth a look definitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) to manage my pdf library. It is actually a reference manager, but it does fit your criteria:

- It is free
- Organizes and views pdf files
- Ability to add and save annotations and highlights
- You can associate the .pdf extension with it as the default application
- Ability to add tags or generate them automatically

Additionally, you could easily sync your library across multiple devices using their cloud

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, it seems good, just I wish it faster on open the document and no need to synch or check .... (is it an option to make it just a local application?)

Comment: @Ahmad I do not know of a feature to disable sync, but there is a workaround desribed [here](http://support.mendeley.com/customer/portal/questions/935580-disable-online-sync). It instructs to enter incorrect proxy details under Tools -> Options -> Connection to confuse the server

Comment: thank you again, it seems nice and I use it, however still a local faster application is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Calibre ebook manager](http://www.calibre-ebook.com/) to manage pdf files as well as other types of ebooks:

- Free *both financially and FOSS*
- view pdf files (editing or highlighting tools is a plus) - *No uses your system default*
- Open pdf fils (as the default application) - *No uses your system default but does add a add to calibre library to the context menu*
- allow tag the file - *Various tags can be added and searched on*
- manage files according to the tags or other properties *Yes*

### Other features:

- Support for lots of ebook formats
- Can convert between ebook formats - with some [limitations](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#pdfconversion) when it comes to pdf inputs.
- Can load items from your library to your mobile/tablet
- Can act as a web server for your content.
- Advanced searches
- Cross Platform

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue widely encountered at research. There [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) is a tool widely used. The viewing and marking capabilities of PDFs is "outsourced" to a viewer of choice. [FoxIt Reader](https://www.foxit.com/pdf-reader/) is a fast tool. I personally use Acrobat Reader.

"tagging" is implemented by the [Groups Feature](https://docs.jabref.org/finding-sorting-and-cleaning-entries/groups) of JabRef:

[image: Groups Screenshot]