# A software to index PDF files and manage collections

Tags: pdf, document-management, document-indexing

I work for a company that handles hundreds of PDF files. Mostly datasheets, technical drawings and forms and records.

I am responsible for producing for each project a set of "Dossiers", with content reuse (reuse of certificates, for instance)

I want a software that would be able to index all my files, tag them, and classify them in collections.

Collections should then be exportable into zip files or folders for printing, further manipulation, ...

Requirements :

- Ability to index pdf files from multiple sources (smb drives, local drives)
- Group files into collections or groups, that could then be exported
- Ability to generate sub-sets of documents based on filters/criteria (like type, tags, ..)
- Ability to export sub-sets

It would be a plus if the software is able to :

- Allow scripting of tasks
- Generate collections based on table of contents

I reviewed benubird pdf, and I would like something maybe more powerful/broad
I also reviewed softwares like nuxeo and alfresco, but I'm afraid I'm looking for something else

I don't even know how this kind of software is called, so if anyone could put me on the right track, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Related question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11391/6834

Comment: Actually the software i'm looking needs to be suitable for technical dms

Comment: What do you mean by "Generate collections based on table of contents"? How would you express the table of contents? By writing file names in a text file for instance?

Answer (score 1):

[Qiqqa](http://www.qiqqa.com) is a freeware and freemium reference management software for Windows.  While intended for academic researchers its features may suit your task of managing datasheets and technical records.

Qiqqa meets your requirements 1-4.  See [Qiqqa Features](http://www.qiqqa.com/About/Features) for details

Regarding your "nice to haves":
Although Qiqqa doesn't have scripting capability there are some automation features like auto-tagging and assigning tags at import corresponding to source folder name.

It may be possible to use the program's cross reference feature, which automatically finds which papers in your library reference other papers in your library, to "generate collection based on table of contents".

Answer (score 0):

[Alfresco](http://alfresco.com/) covers all of your needs, except it does not handle files that are on external drives:

- Group documents by categories or tags
- Export a folder to ZIP and download using for instance [this addon](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/compress-and-download-share-action-zip)
- Search based on categories/tags/titles/plain-text/metadata
- You can not export not save sub-set though, unfortunately, this would be a custom development
- Create "rules" using the graphical interface, or using JavaScript if needed