# Software to manage files (with tags)

Tags: linux, file-management, ubuntu, information-management

I am searching for a software with which I am able to organize my files.

For example there are some media players (e.g. Amarok) that provide what I am looking for songs: ratings, tags, etc. However, I search for a software for arbitrary files, in particular scientific papers and books (but not solely) for references.

There exist reference manager software, but I'm not aware that they manage the PDFs themselves. Also, managing PDFs is only part of it - I also want to mange other files (e.g. videos, images, whatnot). Most importantly is tagging to me.

I am running Kubuntu (soon to be 16.04).

PS: Not sure if https://www.alfresco.com/products/community/download (https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Installing_Alfresco_Lab_3_Stable_on_Ubuntu_8.10 - but nothing for new Ubuntus) and http://www.nuxeo.com/downloads/ which I got from [A software to index PDF files and manage collections](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/a-software-to-index-pdf-files-and-manage-collections) is what I am searching for …

Comment: By "files", do you mean document files only, as your mentioning of Alfresco indicates? If so, you might wish to take a look at [other questions tagged `document-management`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/document-management) – especially those [tagged `linux` and having answers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[document-management]+[linux]+answers%3A1).

Comment: @Izzy: Depends on what you mean by document...

Comment: See the [tag-wiki](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/document-management/info) :) Basically, something you edit to store data in (as opposed to e.g. archives with software distributions). So if your focus is on office documents, PDFs and the like, that's what our `document-management` tag is for. Also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Calibre might be exactly what you are looking for: https://calibre-ebook.com/download

I use it extensively to manage my various documents and books that I have acquired in my line of work.  It is exceptional at managing books and you can set up a folder to drop files into for it to catalog.  You can tag to your hearts content as well as grouping by series or other custom data groups if that is something you need.

You can store multiple file format types for a given entry in Calibre if you have a pdf and kindle book, for example.  I will mention one more thing since  you specifically said "files" in your question, and that is that if you start trying to organize other files (like AutoCAD drawings, for instance), you will have some issues trying to group information.  Calibre primarily groups things by author so if you had a ton of files from people you worked with, they will all end up in one massive directory.